# String reversal in Java in space

Tags: java, reverse

I was preparing for my SWE interview, my primary language in Java. I encountered a question that reverses a string in space. I searched more and in space means in `O(1)`. Is it possible to do it in Java as the strings are immutable?

Comment: wait. do you mean to swap the line of strings like `string` to `gnirts`?

Comment: You are correct that strings in Java are immutable, but even if you were talking about reversing an array of char, it's literally impossible to reverse a piece of memory faster than O(n).

Comment: in space in this context just means without creating another String variable. See [Reverse a string in place in Java](https://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/24/reversing-a-string-in-java-in-place/)

Comment: @azurefrog Space, not speed.

Comment: @Orin2005 doesn't that solution create another string variable?